# How to get string value from a Java field via reflection?

Tags: java, string, reflection

I have a method:

```
public void extractStringFromField(Class<?> classToInspect) {
    Field[] allFields = classToInspect.getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field field : allFields) {
        if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            System.out.println("Field name: " + field.getName());

            // How to get the actual value of the string?!?!
            // String strValue = ???
        }
    }
}
```

When this runs I get output like:

```
Field name: java.lang.String
```

Now how do I extract the actual string value into `strValue`, **using reflection?**

Comment: Shouldn't it be? `System.out.println("Field name: " + field.getName());`

Comment: Yes - cut n' paste error!

Comment: You want to get the value of which field? On which object?

Comment: If `classToInspect` is a `Widget`, and the `Widget` class has a String field called `fizz`, and the value of that `Widget#fizz` instance is "buzz", then I want to get the `buzz` string into an actual `String` instance.

Comment: @TicketMonster A field only makes sense either as a static field of a Class or as an instance field. You therefore have to specify which instance it is (or `null` when it's static) with the `Field#get(Object)` method. Internally, it looks like `Object.Field` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you need a reference to an instance of the class. You would want to call [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) and pass in the reference, casting the return to a String.

You can use get as follows:

```
String strValue = (String) field.get (objectReference);
```

Comment: It's an unfortunate aspect of the API that you need to pass in a reference even if the field is static.

Comment: It also may be worth noting that you might need to make sure that the field is accessible like so: field.setAccessible(true);

Comment: I tried passing null and got a NullPointerException in Java 1.7.0_79

Comment: answering to @th3morg : it works if you pass an instance ( new Foo() ) instead of null

Answer (score 8):

In ideal situations,`Class` does not hold data. It merely holds the information about the structure and behavior of its instances and Instances of the `Classes` hold your data to use. So your `extractStringFromField` method can not extract values unless you pass any instances (from where it will actually extract values).

If the name of the parameter of the reference, you are passing to extract value is `instance`, then you can easily get what you want like bellow:

```
String strValue = (String)field.get(instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just usefull example code for reflection fields:

```
Field[] fields = InsanceName.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {      //array for fields names

System.out.println("Fields: " + Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers())); // modyfiers
System.out.println("Fields: " + field.getType().getName());  //type var name
System.out.println("Fields: " + field.getName());        //real var name
field.setAccessible(true);                                //var readable
System.out.println("Fields: " + field.get(InsanceName));  //get var values  
System.out.println("Fields: " + field.toString());     //get "String" values
System.out.println("");  //some space for readable code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. This Thread somewhat helped. Just for reference if somebody else stumbles upon this thread. I used the StringBuilder class to convert so basically:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(field.get(object))
```

Which has multiple advantages. One that you do not explicitly cast (which btw. causes problems with primitive types int vs. Integer) but also of being more efficient if you have multiple string operations sequentialy. In time critical code parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
String strValue = field.getName().toString();
```

Full code looks like this:

```
public static void extractStringFromField(Class<?> Login) {
    Field[] allFields = Login.getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field field : allFields) {
        String strValue = field.getName().toString();
//          if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            System.out.println("Field name: " + strValue);
        }
    }
```