# Iterating through a hashmap and changing the values using reflection

Tags: dynamic, reflection, while-loop, hashmap, field

So I'm coding a gene algorithm and ideally I start off by placing some float variables in a hashmap. These will be the genes that are passed on to different objects.

ie

```
genes.put("mass", 200);
genes.put("lifespan",0);
genes.put("intelligence",0);
genes.put("dexterity",0);
genes.put("endurance",0);
```

then later I want hashmap values to be updated when there is a change in the variable. This is the code I have so far;

```
if(updategenes){

  for ( String key : genes.keySet() ) {
      System.out.println( key );
      try{
     String a = key;
     Field field = a.getClass().getField(key); 
     genes.put(key,field);

     }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
     }catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     }}
  updategenes = false;
}
```

only issue is it wont accept field as an int even though thats the only possible type that could ever be in field at the time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
int strValue = (int) field.get (key);
```

[How to get string value from a Java field via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461442/how-to-get-string-value-from-a-java-field-via-reflection/17461487)

Comment: What’s good for `String` isn’t necessarily good for `int`. You can simply call `field.getInt(key)`, then you don’t need to convert an `Object` to `int`.